# How to setup servlet-api.jar to Windows Environment

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm facing problem related to servlet packages.

Here are the errors.

> import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
>
> test\OneServlet.java:5: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
> import javax.servlet.ServletException;
>
> test\OneServlet.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not
> exist import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
>
> test\OneServlet.java:7: error: package javax.servlet.http does not
> exist import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
>
> test\OneServlet.java:8: error: package javax.servlet.http does not
> exist import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

After searching allot I found two solution. One is to setup the path variable to `servlet-api.jar` So I added this path to `C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar` and try to recompile but still Same error.

The second solution I found is to use the -cp flag.

I try to compile the file using this command.

`javac -cp C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar test/*.java`

Then it works fine.

I wonder why it is not working with environment Variable? I also added the same path `C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar` to CLASSPATH variable. but still not works why?

I want to setup it using windows environment and want to leave -cp flags each time.

Comment: Environment variables are for .exe files.Are you using any IDE?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy no I'm not using any IDE. I'm using notepad++ and cmd.

Comment: Better to grab one, try eclipse..